# Software Center stuck on loading screen

Tags: 11.10, software-center

Ive just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and updated it. When I run Software Center it just sits at the loading screen forever. Software center did work before I added the canonical-partners source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion:

Reinstall software center by doing the following:

1. Open a terminal and type

   ```
   sudo apt-get install synaptic
   ```
2. Then, run synaptic and type in the search field **software center**.
3. In the results right click on **software-center** package and select "**mark for complete removal**".
4. Click "mark" on the next dialog that tells you that also **ubuntu-desktop** will be removed. Then click the apply button and go on.
5. Then, when the removal process is done, find again the **software-center** package, right click, and select *mark for installation*.
6. Also find the **ubuntu-desktop** package and mark it for installation.
7. Finally, click the apply button.
8. Check then if Software Center gets stuck again on loading screen

Comment: Instead of uninstalling then reinstalling I selected **mark for reinstallation** which fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uninstalling then reinstalling like Paul said, I selected **mark for reinstallation**. This fixed the Software Center.

Comment: Glad you fixed it  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could have stumbled into [bug #891499](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/891499). According to the bug comments, the following might help:

1. Backup cataloged_times.p

   ```
   sudo cp /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/cataloged_times.p /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/cataloged_times.p.backup
   ```
2. Delete cataloged_times.p

   ```
   sudo rm /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/cataloged_times.p
   ```

Comment: If you get permission problems, see [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67160/software-center-doesnt-stop-to-load). They suggest: sudo apt-get purge software-center apt-xapian-index && sudo rm -rf /var/cache/software-center && sudo apt-get install software-center apt-xapian-index